Aiogram_calendar. Нет документации в библиотеки
как решить проблему? Делаю крупный проект, нашел афигенную библиотеку для создание календаря в телеграмм боте. Вот либа: https://pypi.org/project/aiogram-calendar/0.1.1/
Так как использую версию библиотеки 0.1.1 (Aiogram 2.25 поддерживает максимум эту версию), нет примера кода. Вот моя версия кода:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import aiogram_calendar
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

TOKEN = 'ЧЧЧЧЧЧЧЧЧЧ'
storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='markdown')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def x(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Привет', reply_markup=await aiogram_calendar.DialogCalendar().start_calendar())

@dp.callback_query_handler(aiogram_calendar.DialogCalendar)
async def process_dialog_calendar(callback_query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: CallbackData):
    selected, date = await aiogram_calendar.DialogCalendar().process_selection(callback_query, callback_data)
    if selected:
        await callback_query.message.answer(
            f'You selected {date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

Но выходит ошибка:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-14' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("process_dialog_calendar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_data'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ПРОГРАМИРОВАНИЕ\МЫВМЕСТЕ\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: process_dialog_calendar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback_data'

